# Angular - Unable to set default value from inside a component when using ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, typescript

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/cMu3lI3PkxHRErJE3T93?p=preview

I've got a few components which all seem to have the same problem, and that is that I can't set a default value for `ngModel` or `formControlName` when using `ControlValueAccessor`.

For example in the demo we have a select which provides better UX and visuals but in the `ngOnInit` I can't set the model to be the first item in the provided options if the select has a `required` input set to `true`.

If `true`, the select will always have a value. However now it only works after you actually clicked on an option.

One "solution" would be to always set the value in the parent of where it is being used. But that would require a lot of unnecessary code and I don't want to have to do that. Especially since setting a default value shouldn't be a problem.

So here's a short snippet of what we're working with:

```
  private _model: any;

  set model(val) {
    this._model = val;
  }

  get model() {
    return this._model;
  }

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

  registerOnChange(fn: () => any) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}

  writeValue(value: any) {

    if (value !== undefined) {
      this.model = value;
      this.cd.markForCheck();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    if (!this.model && this.required) {
      this.model = this.options[0];
    }
    else if (!this.required) {
      this.model = null;
    }

    this.propagateChange(this.model);
  }
```

As you can see in the demo, the setting of the model in `ngOnInit` isn't working.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `this.propagateChange(this.model);` this function has not registered yet.

So i know two workarounds

1) Update model after `propagateChange` was assigned

```
export const NOOP: any = () => {};
...

propagateChange = NOOP;

registerOnChange(fn: () => any) {
  this.propagateChange = fn;
  if(this.required) {
    fn(this.model);
  }
}

writeValue(value: any) {
  if (value !== undefined && this.propagateChange !== NOOP) {
    this.model = value;
    this.cd.markForCheck();
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZtoByDuMlAXzPm5gd0o2?p=preview)**

2) Use `ngModelChange` event

```
@Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();

this.ngModelChange.emit(this.model);
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8jL2KGnR77VoCyrlzHKw?p=preview)**

Comment: Already tested the ngModelChange thing and it's horrible, it will break in some scenarios where the actual value won't be set. So I'd remove that from the answer :) The other solution seems to work but it seems odd that you have to "workaround" it for such a simple thing to work. But for now I'll go with it. Thanks.

Comment: Actually this solution doesn't allow the real value to be set either, it will always set it to the first value of options. See https://plnkr.co/edit/IcaPj582CeLzzsSMqhmE?p=preview

Comment: What do you mean? Can you reproduce it?

Comment: See plunkr in above comment. I set the value in the constructor of app component but it still gives me the first value of the options passed in.

Comment: `sortBy = this.options[0];`? I don't see any constructor

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZtoByDuMlAXzPm5gd0o2?p=preview Maybe I pasted the wrong one. Here it is.

Comment: I mean it's not working when `required` is `true` and you have a value for `sortBy` already. https://plnkr.co/edit/MTMtNbHafoAL2GidsypF?p=preview

Comment: We're on very thin ice here.. lol. But I guess it's a solution.